# MS SQL Selecting valid occurrence / Ignoring others

Tags: mysql, sql

We're running a query to select 3 values from a table.   Column 1 is a long string(not unique), column 2 is an integer (also a sequence number, but it's a sequence number for each occurrence of column 1), and a column 3 which has value 1-4/empty/null.

We only want to retrieve/include the record when:

- Column 3 has the values 2 or 3 'later'/higher record than any 1's (if it exists)
- OR: If the latest record is blank/null in column 3 the previous record is
  to be checked. If this record has the value 2 or 3 in column 3 that record should be
  retrieved/included. If it has value 1 it should not be included.

Here's first two examples of records that we don't want to include.
First, this one has 1 in column 3 and should not be included;

```
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |     Record no    |        Column 1     |     Column 2     |      Column 3    |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         3        |    1000-fff-aaa     |        3         |         1        |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         2        |    1000-fff-aaa     |        2         |         2        |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         1        |    1000-fff-aaa     |        1         |         1        |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

This one has blank in the latest record (3), so previous record (2) is checked and has value 1, should not be included

```
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |     Record no    |        Column 1     |     Column 2     |      Column 3    |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         3        |    1000-fff-bbb     |        3         |                  |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         2        |    1000-fff-bbb     |        2         |         1        |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         1        |    1000-fff-bbb     |        1         |         2        |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

So example of one that **should** be included:
Column 3 is blank so we check the previous record (2) and the column 3 has the value 2 so record no 2 should be included

```
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |     Record no    |        Column 1     |     Column 2     |      Column 3    |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         3        |    1000-fff-ccc     |        3         |                  |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         2        |    1000-fff-ccc     |        2         |         2        |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         1        |    1000-fff-ccc     |        1         |         1        |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

In the last example the top record has the value 3 in column 3 and should be included. PS: It should only select the last record if there's multiple valid records, in this example only show record no 3.

```
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |     Record no    |        Column 1     |     Column 2     |      Column 3    |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         3        |    1000-fff-ddd     |        3         |         3        |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         2        |    1000-fff-ddd     |        2         |         2        |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
   |         1        |    1000-fff-ddd     |        1         |         1        |
   |------------------|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

So in short we just want to retrieve the last valid record from the selection. Any ideas or pointers?
We have come to the point where we did retrieve the latest record with value 2 or 3 in column 3, however there was a newer record with the value 1 in column so it should not have been retrieved.

Comment: I am unclear on which rows you want included in the result set.

Comment: In which of the example? In the two first tables I don't want any rows retrieved. In table 3 I want record no 2, and in table 4 I want record 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.column3 IN ('2', '3') -- only 2 or 3 needed
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM table t2
                   WHERE t1.column1 = t2.column1       -- the same entity
                     AND t1.column2 < t2.column2       -- and above by sequence
                     AND t2.column3 IN ('1', '2', '3') -- 1-3 not allowed above
                 )
```

?

Comment: As this was a part of a larger query I did a small tweak to your code and it worked great! Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

It may sound not relevant to the question but I really think it would be better to refactor the model, do the calculation on INSERT and mark the inserted row accordingly. Why? Because EVERY time you run you final query (when you get the answer here) it should do 2 calculation-intensive things: 1) compute the "last" row, 2) compute "previous" row for case 2 in your conditions. Both tasks have to order all the dataset which will grow over time (I hope you work not record-wise, because then you can use CASE with as much subselects for each condition as you need).
On insert it's quite easy to find the "last" row: just MAX(Record no). Then you just compare your new row and that last row (it will act like previous).